# showing span(ax) = span(x) for any $a \ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I know this is obvious, but I'm fairly new to spanning sets and just want to make sure proofs convey what I already know.

My attempt:

Let vector $v \in span(ax)$. Then, $v = k_{1}ax$. Let $k_{1}a = c_{1}$. Hence, $v = k_{1}ax = c_{1}x$. Therfore, v lives inside span{x}.

Let vector $w \in span(x)$. Then, $w = k_{1}x = {k_{1}\over a}(ax)$ (alowed since a $\ne$ 0). Therfore, w lives inside span{ax}.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: You do not need a new name for $k_1a$.

Comment: Note that this is still true when $X$ is a set of vectors, not just a lone vector. (Where $aX := \{ax\mid x \in X\}$.)